# Change container width to more than 32767 with jquery in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, opera

I want to make a mini timeline with jquery and for this timeline to have a width more than 32767 px. When I change it with jquery `$(".timelinecontainer").width(32767);` in Opera does not change it, but in others browsers it works.

Can you give me advice on getting it to work in Opera ?

Comment: It's probably just an Opera bug.  I'm guessing the width is hardcoded in Opera to 32767 or less, so there would be no way to go larger than this.  Maybe there's a way you can file a bug with them.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that Opera keeps the window width as a short and thus is not able to handle values larger than 32767.  You should probably change your approach anyway and scale the timeline to fit the current window, then give the ability to zoom in on portions of it.  I think your interface will look and work better this way.   The way you seem to be doing it, the user will have to do a lot of scrolling to view the timeline and won't ever be able to see it in its entirety.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure I'll get flamed for saying this but--you could just ignore Opera.

If you like how things look in the other browsers (IE,FF,Safari/Chrome), then I'd say you've got 99% of your bases covered.

You may want to file a bug against Opera, of course. (though I guess it could be jquery--it may have a different code path for Opera). If you could make a simple HTML page to reproduce the problem, you'd know. Then, attach it to the bug report.

Comment: It's hard to see how it could be jQuery.  Javascript doesn't have different int sizes and I don't know why they would make a check for the width in Opera just for the sake of making it different.  You could actually look at the jQuery code, though, and see.

Comment: I agree with you, I'm just trying to be fair to all possibly guilty parties. This should be easy to confirm with a simple Html page, maybe with a little JS, if necessary.

Comment: Since JS can't create a "short" or "long" only an int or a number I can't see how jQuery would be at fault.  Opera likely has the bug, but then I don't think they expected a (32 x screen width) element to be a common occurrence either. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old Opera bug which for some reason they can't resolve. Opera is popular only in some regions and mostly this bug is ignored by the developers.

There is no automated solution for this. As a quick solution you can detect web-browser in your script and limit the width for Opera. As an example - scroll [this guitar tab](http://rockby.net/en/gtp.php?tab=Limp-Bizkit/Behind-Blue-Eyes/3#multitrack) to an end in Opera.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this is indeed a bug in the current Opera versions. The good news is that we're working on fixing it (I work for Opera, so I know what's going on there :)), so in the not too distant future your script should start working as you expect.

I'd actually suggest that if the workaround the first answer above suggests is too hard to implement, you should ignore the problem and wait for the Opera upgrade that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug and it has been fixed in the Opera 12 pre-alphas available from http://my.opera.com/desktopteam

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug with Opera.

Coincidentally,  I was seeing it for the first time just yesterday. In my situation I have an inner container with `width:9999em` and an outer container that uses `overflow:hidden` and `scrollLeft()` to create a carousel. In Opera the `scrollLeft()` stops responding at that width.

File a bug with Opera: https://bugs.opera.com/wizard/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an Opera bug to me, too.

Why not take a look at Simile's Timeline project (http://simile.mit.edu/timeline/) and see how they've done it?